# Maxpulse code doesn't want to work, really simple

Tags: python

I can't figure out why this simple code isn't working?

```
maxpuls = 220

ålder = input("Hej! Vi vill mäta din maxpuls skriv in din ålder här:")

print("Detta är din maxpuls:" + (ålder - maxpuls))
```

Comment: I would recommend updating the name of this post to make it more relevant: e.g. "how to concatenate a string and int in python."

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works. You either have encoding issues because you are using high-ascii characters in your script, or it is because you have to convert the input to an integer.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

maxpuls = 220

ålder = input("Hej! Vi vill mäta din maxpuls skriv in din ålder här:")

print("Detta är din maxpuls:" + str ( int(ålder) - maxpuls))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hej, this is because ålder/maxpuls are int type and you're concatenating them with a string. To fix that, cast (ålder - maxpuls) as a string.

```
maxpuls = 220

ålder = input("Hej! Vi vill mäta din maxpuls skriv in din ålder här:")

print("Detta är din maxpuls:" + str(int(ålder) - maxpuls))here
```

Trevlig dag, kompis!